# Count Files based on the first two letters

Tags: python

I would love it if someone could help me. I know nearly nothing about Python, so please excuse the naivety. I have spent two days reading through this site trying to get beyond where I am at.

I wrote this code (well saw it on the this site for the most part):

```
    import os
    path = '/the/path/to/the/I want/to/count'
    file_count = sum((len(f) for _, _,f in os.walk(path)))
    print "Number of files: ",file_count
```

I get my file count, but it takes a while. Is there faster code? And it went into sub directories I presume as the file count was higher then what I expected.

My ultimate goal is to get a count of files based on the first two letters of each file. ie. AL, AR, AZ. Could I possibly get an example of what I would have to add for that?

Comment: You're not telling us *exactly* what's needed... Are you interested in files in sub dirs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `os.walk()` traverses subdirectories.

If you need counts grouped by the first two letters, I'd use a [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class for that:

```
import os
from collections import Counter

path = '/the/path/to/the/I want/to/count'
counts = Counter(fname[:2] for _, _, files in os.walk(path) for fname in files)
for initials, count in counts.most_common():
    print '{}: {:>20}'.format(initials, count)
```

This would traverse the subdirectories, and collect counts grouped by the first two characters of each filename encountered, then print those counts ordered by most to least common.

If you do *not* want to traverse subdirectories, use [`os.listdir()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) instead; it returns just the names in a given directory (including both filenames and directory names). You could then use [`os.path.isfile()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) to filter out those names that are just filenames:

```
counts = Counter(fname[:2] for fname in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, fname)))
```

If you are looking for files with as specific extension, look for that extension instead of the `isfile()` test; presumably no subdirectory is going to use the same extension:

```
counts = Counter(fname[:2] for fname in os.listdir(path) if fname.endswith('.pdf'))
```

Comment: I really don't think you want `isfile` in there if speed is important.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Do you have a better option to filter out subdirectories?

Comment: os.walk() needs to stat the entries to build its directory and filenames lists - it should be about as fast if you do it yourself. You could "from os.path import isfile" so you have fewer lookups, but that won't make much of a difference either.

Comment: Both Windows and Linux return whether the file is a directory, I'm surprised `listdir` doesn't expose that.

Comment: I get this error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lisdir' when I run it with os.listdir() and os.path.isfile(). The first example worked, but looked in subdirectories, which given the time frame I deal with may not be a big deal.

Comment: @JasonPeltier: I made a typo, since corrected. It's `listdir` with a `t`. Please do try again.

Comment: OKAY, did it on a real time folder and it works perfect, the subdirectories will not be a concern for me when i am using it, they come later. I only want to look at .pdf files, do I put that in after for and before files?

Comment: @JasonPeltier: You can add a `fname.endswith('.pdf')` in there instead of the `isfile()` test.

Comment: I just looked up [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) and realized it had some advice for pruning the search - you don't need `listdir` after all.

Comment: @MarkRansom: `os.walk` uses `os.listdir` internally. Using `os.walk` to then prune *all subdirs* is only going to be slower. `os.walk` uses `os.path.isdir` instead of `os.path.isfile` but those two don't differ in their performance cost, they use the same OS calls.

Comment: IF I wanted to exclude files that contain a certain word, i.e. "b-lue", what would need to be put into the code?

Comment: @JasonPeltier: at the end (after for fname in files` add `if 'b-lue not in fname`, or for the last example in my answer, use `and 'b-lue' not in fname`.

Comment: @Martijn: I used the middle example you wrote, so I do not have 'fname in files'.

Comment: You do have `fname` in a loop and an `if` test; just append `and 'b-lue' not in fname`.

Comment: @Martijn: Okay, got it in the right place, thank-you. Really slowed down the process, but the  output is great.

Comment: @JasonPeltier: you could test for the `'b-lue' not in fname` *first* (so before testing if it is an actual file):  `if 'b-lue' not in fname and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, fname))`

Comment: @Martijn: It will always be a file name throughout the directory. It is working as I want, do mind another minute or so.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i need to rephrase my question I posted. The code works great and has for months. Would it be onerous to change it so the day of the month is included. It would sort by day first i.e 17 (day) PR (1st 2 letters) 20 (count of files) then 18 - PR - 10. Figure it would take a lot of time, but that is not a concern.

Comment: @JasonPeltier: You'd alter what you are counting, right now that is `fname[:2]`, but you can make that expression also generate something else, like `'{} - {}'.format(fname[2:4], fname[:2])`, if the day of the month is part of the filename as 3rd and 4th characters.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the day of the month would never be a set number of characters from the first two letters; it would be after the first "/".

Comment: @JasonPeltier: Then extract that part; if you have trouble with that, search here on Stack Overflow then perhaps open a new question to get help with that.

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
len(glob.glob('/the/path/to/the/I want/to/count/AL*'))
len(glob.glob('/the/path/to/the/I want/to/count/AR*'))
```

etc.

Comment: The directory is rescanned for each glob but the operating system is going to cache the directory info in ram so it may be tolerable.

Comment: oops, i just missed the speed part of the whole question. Its not a right idea to traverse multiple times if its quite a files.